# Conditional Props - pass a props only when the value is not null

Tags: vue.js

I would like to send the props ONLY when the value is not null. 
Put another way, , I want to use the props default value in the child when the value is null.

Do you imagine something more elegant than this?

```
<template>
    <div v-if="options">
        <grid :options="options" />
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        <grid />
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to pass `undefined` to get the default value:

```
<grid :options="options || undefined" />
```

See this pen as an example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/expBGP

Comment: @Ricky what are you saying? "Every time the user needs to use the grid component they will need to pass options || undefined". No they won't. They can just not use that prop at all. This is just about a scenario where the component consumer needs to make that decision at runtime, which is not the regular case.