# Access JSON object using a array of keys Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I need to access into myObject using a generic function.

Data:

```
myObject = {
    "name": "Caroline",
    "number": 32,
    "country": {
        "province": {
            "city": {
                "NY": 67989876,
                "Boston": 454346,
            }
        }
    }
}

myArray = ["country", "province", "city"]
```

The solution would be:

```
myObject["country"]["province"]["city"]
```

I want rewrite after myObject, then the solution can not be a copy

```
myObject["country"]["province"]["city"] = "New datas"
```

Comment: Hi,  Slightly confused here, is it always guaranteed that your object will contain this hierarchy of keys? What if there are more keys in myArray?

Comment: It is always guaranteed that your object will contain this hierarchy of keys. myArray basically is containing the path.

Comment: Is it a JSON object or an object literal? Do we need to parse the JSON first or is it already an accesible object?

Comment: What is going on? I don't understand a thing in this. Is this a question?

Comment: You have asked a fair number of questions on stack overflow and only once marked an answer correct. That's considered a little rude around here and reduces one's motivation to help you.

Comment: I always have marked when the first person give me the correct solution. Check the profile.

Comment: @SaraNJ maybe you misunderstood me — you should select the correct answers (that's different from an up vote). It will put a check box next to it like you did with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54351463/conditional-props-pass-a-props-only-when-the-value-is-not-null) in January. I identifies the question as solved, with helps other people looking for answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = myObject;
for (var i in myArray) {
    data = data[myArray[i]];
}

alert(data);
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g2uyb8rn/

Shorter version by @JeremyThille is:

```
var data = myObject;
for (let i of myArray) data = data[i];

alert(data);
```

Comment: Or even shorter : `for (let i of myArray) data = data[i];`

Comment: @JeremyThille I suppose it can be another answer)

Comment: Nah, it's just a variant of yours, but the result is the same.

Comment: Added as another variant.

Comment: OP said she wanted a generic function. This is not a function

Comment: Oh, come on. Wrap this in `function(myArray){ }`, job done